# what is the mapping signature in solidity?

Tags: mapping, solidity, call, smartcontracts

I want to make an external call from my contract to another contracts mapping I'm just not sure what to enter as the function signature if I use:

```
callee.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(functionSignature, inputs)
```

because the function signature is usually something like "functionName(inputs)"
but it doesn't work like that with the mapping which is something like:
mapping(address => bool) public mappingName.
can I write something like: "mappingName(address)" as the mapping signature?

Answer (score 0):

All `public` properties autogenerate a [getter function](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#getter-functions) that allows you to read one item at a time.

```
mapping(address => bool) public mappingName;
```

autogenerates a function (in the bytecode, not in the source code) that could be represented in the source code like this

```
function mappingName(address _myVar) public returns (bool)
```

So yes, the signature is exactly as you say in the question

```
mappingName(address)
```